# Time complexity of the recursive algorithm two factors

Tags: algorithm

I have a relation of:

```
T (n) = T(n/3) + T(2n/3) + f(n^2)
```

I want to find the time time complexity using Master Theorem. I believe the Time complexity is `O(n^2)`

We have `(1/9)n^2 + (4/9)n^2 = (5/9)n^2` children. Based on this, can I conclude the time complexity  is `O(n^2)`?

Comment: What is `f`? ----

Answer (score 0):

We can elaborate solution using [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) (more general than Master theorem)

Solving

```
(1/3)^p + (2/3)^p = 1
```

gives

```
p = 1
```

So

```
T(x) = Theta(x * (1 + Int[1..x](u^2/u^2*du))) = 
       Theta(x * (1 + Int[1..x](du))) = 
       Theta(x * (1 + x - 1) = 
       Theta(x^2)
```

and your assumption is right

Comment: I have read some of your answers and it seems you could help me out with a math problem I have, if you have time for it, it would mean a lot to me if you could check out my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599014/3d-create-a-point-to-a-distance-taking-in-consideration-the-player-y-rotation