# 3D Create a point to a distance taking in consideration the Player Y rotation

Tags: java, point, quaternions

I need to define a 2D plane area in front of a Point(which is our player position) and check which Points(enemies) are within it.
In the game it is used to determine what enemies are within the "box" in front of us with X width, Y height and Z length.

I need help calculating the bottom left and top right points of the plane.

Input : We know the player position and we know the player rotation. Only the player Y rotation matters, as the plane should always be in front of the player.

We know the plane width and length. Height is irrelevant in this case, I know how to calculate it. If the width is 8 meters and the length 20, if player position is 0,0,0 the bottom left point would be X= -4 / Y = 0 / Z = 0 and the top right point would be X=4 / Y = 0 / Z = 20

My code only works when the player Y rotation is 0, because I simply add the width/length to current X and Z values. I need the correct math formula to determine where the bottom left and top right points would be, taking in parameter the Player's Y rotation, so that the plane area will always be in the same direction that the player is facing

Here is a visual representation of what I need exactly :

https://gyazo.com/fd5ad0e393f6db8236ee7fd766e7286b

`

```
float AreaWidth = 8;
float AreaLength = 20;
float AreaHeight = 10;

Point AreaBTMLeftPoint = new Point(PlayerPosition.getX()-(AreaWidth/2), 
PlayerPosition.getLoc().getY(), PlayerPosition.getLoc().getZ());

Point AreaTOPRightPoint = new Point(PlayerPosition.getLoc().getX()+ 
(AreaWidth/2), PlayerPosition.getLoc().getY(), 
PlayerPosition.getLoc().getZ()+(AreaLength));

float AreaBTMX = AreaBTMLeftPoint.getX();
float AreaBTMZ = AreaBTMLeftPoint.getZ();
float AreaTOPX = AreaTOPRightPoint.getX();
float AreaTOPZ = AreaTOPRightPoint.getZ();
float AreaMaxY = PlayerPosition.getLoc().getY()+(AreaHeight/2);
float AreaMinY = PlayerPosition.getLoc().getY()-(AreaHeight/2);

if (TargetPosition.getLoc().getX() > AreaBTMX && 
TargetPosition.getLoc().getX() < AreaTOPX &&
TargetPosition.getLoc().getY() > AreaMinY &&
TargetPosition.getLoc().getY() < AreaMaxY &&
TargetPosition.getLoc().getZ() > AreaBTMZ && 
TargetPosition.getLoc().getZ() < AreaTOPZ) {

This target is inside the area, do stuff.
```

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let player position is P, direction angle is Fi, target position is T.
Unit direction vector D:

```
d.x = cos(Fi) //don't forget about radians
d.y = sin(Fi)
```

Difference vector

```
PT = T - P = (T.x - P.x, T.y - P.y)
```

Perpendicular distance from T to direction line of player is length of orthogonal projection

```
perplen = Abs(Pt x D) =                  //cross product
          Abs(PT.x * d.y - Pt.y * d.x)
compare it with (AreaWidth/2)
```

Distance along direction line:

```
alonglen = (Pt .dot. D) =                  //dot product
           PT.x * d.x + PT.y * d.y
it should be >=0 and <= than AreaLength
```

If both conditions are true, target lies in inclined rectangle

Proof-of-concept Delphi code:

```
var
  i, px, py, tx, ty, XX, YY, ptx, pty: Integer;
  perplen, alonglen: Double;
  wdt, lng: Integer;
  Fi, cs, sn: Double;
begin
  px := 300;    py := 300;
  wdt := 150;   lng := 250;
  Fi := Pi / 6;   cs := Cos(Fi);   sn := Sin(Fi);
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.Ellipse(px - 5, py - 5, px + 6, py + 6);  //player

  Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
  Canvas.MoveTo(px, py);
  XX := px - Round(Wdt / 2 * sn);  YY := py + Round(Wdt / 2 * cs);
  Canvas.LineTo(XX, YY);
  XX := XX + Round(lng * cs);   YY := YY + Round(lng * sn);
  Canvas.LineTo(XX, YY);
  XX := XX + Round(Wdt * sn);   YY := YY - Round(Wdt * cs);
  Canvas.LineTo(XX, YY);
  XX := XX - Round(lng * cs);   YY := YY - Round(lng * sn);
  Canvas.LineTo(XX, YY);
  Canvas.LineTo(px, py);  //rectangle finished

  for i := 0 to 99 do begin
    tx := 100 + Random(600);  //random target
    ty := 100 + Random(600);
    ptx := tx - px;
    pty := ty - py;
    perplen := Abs(ptx * sn - pty * cs);
    alonglen := ptx * cs + pty * sn;
    if (perplen <= Wdt / 2) and (alonglen >= 0) and (alonglen <= lng) then
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlue  // in region
    else
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
    Canvas.Ellipse(tx - 3, ty - 3, tx + 4, ty + 4);
  end;
```

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your time and answer. 
I already got results using your formula but I still have issues such as a target considered in the area when it should not. I am also a bit confused on if I should use the Point.Y or Point.Z, because in the actual 3D environment the Z should be used, not the Y axis (where X is left/right, Y up/down and Z forward/backward. I would like to make sure what is wrong in my code with you. Also if you can explain me what I do wrong so that I know it for next time. Thank you https://pastebin.com/thZi7kvc

Comment: 1) I especially emphasized potential issue with degrees/radians. cos/sin function work with radians - why do you use degrees? 2) I solve 2D problem on OXY plane - you can apply the same approach to OXZ plane without y-coordinates.

Comment: I am still having issue writing the Java code for it. Is there any way we could talk about it by mail, I would really appreciate it. It seems like you know exactly how to do it, and I would like to talk about it more in detail, so we can fix my issue and hopefully you can explain me what I was doing wrong, so that I will know how to do it next time. Email me at bringitongame@gmail.com if you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you again. The Delphi code helped. I am not familiar with Delphi, so I converted it to C# and used it in the Unity engine so that I could have a visual way to debug it. Here is a video showing what I got so far : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEhj9Z_Yddg&feature=youtu.be

In the video, the white cube is the player, the white triangle shows where the player is facing. The Transparent red box is where I want the enemy to be considered inside. The colored lines are a visual debugging of the area we create based on width and length. This is basically my own way to do Canvas.Line.

Comment: Issue 1 : When player Y rotation is 0, you can see in the video that the plane we create is offset 90 degrees to the right instead of being at the same position than the red transparent box. But it is important to note that the code is working, the sphere is indeed recognized as inside when entering the area, working with the correct length.

Comment: Issue 2 : The code does not works well with a player Y rotation different than 0, I need the plane to always be in front of the player, no matter the Y rotation. You can see this by the colored lines going out of shape as soon as we start rotating our player.

Here is my code: https://pastebin.com/wCAf0UK0

Comment: What is value of `Fi = Player.rotation.y;` ? Checking code is correct, mistakes are outside of it.

Comment: You can see Player.rotation.y here : https://gyazo.com/17f05a47aa76f2c60b54e7c7671e8911

Comment: It is not angle in radians. For 180 degrees 0.99 is shown instead of 3.14. And value never exceeds 1 - for full cycle it should be in range 0..6.28 or -3.14...3.14

Comment: Ok player.rotation.y is now in radians. 
I still have the issue that the area we are checking is 90degrees to the right of the player direction. When the player Y rotation is 0, the plane we are checking for is oriented 90degrees. New video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhbbyJ7CPfo&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Ok so the area always have an angle with 90 degrees difference, but it is sometimes +90 and sometimes -90. Here is an image showing both angle and radius for 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees player rotation angle. https://gyazo.com/c3db9073460a0d08d668a9c5330bb781

Comment: But this issue is not related to in-rect checking, right? Math zero angle is directed right. Perhaps you have zero at top (same game framework use this orientation)?

Comment: So I converted this code to Java, the Java code is running on our server as game logic. It works as intended, both width and length are accurate. but I still have the same issue with the "rectangle" not being in front of the player, and it is following the same "rules" I sent in the previouse link (https://gyazo.com/c3db9073460a0d08d668a9c5330bb781) , any idea how to solve it? It is ALWAYS 90 degrees, but not always +90 or -90. It depends the player position to the target position. Here is my Java code : https://pastebin.com/bmZm3KiH